# Restrict Drive Letter Selection By Type

Tags: vb.net, drives, drive-letter

I have a form on which a user can select a source drive letter:

```
If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
End If
```

I need to restrict the selection of drive letters to CDROM or USB. My code below validates CDROM drive letters but not USB drive letters:

```
' Check selected drive type is CDROM or USB
Dim Drive As New IO.DriveInfo(TextBox1.Text)
If Drive.IsReady = True Then
    If Not Drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.CDRom or Drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
    MessageBox.Show("Source folder must be CD/DVD or USB.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

How do I configure the code above to validate the drive letter selected is CDROM or USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing brackets on the condition:

```
If Not (Drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.CDRom or Drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable) Then
```

Put simply, you had:

```
If Not A Or B
```

But the `Not` does not apply to B without the brackets - it only applies to A.